# Changing Title Bar Color of Excel Application with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to change the status bar color of excel (the part which usually says Microsoft Excel) on a windows 7 machine.

AFAIK the `application` object doesn't have the title bar as an object and it's not available either on the command bars collection. So I need to use system settings but I don't want to change the status bar for all windows so i can't use the control panel.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: That is not (easily) possible.

Comment: It seems so... i failed to find an answer to this question on the web

Comment: As far as I know, this ability does not exist in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago, there was an utility can adjust the color by (1) the icon's main color or, (2) application's title (user define).

Try google "Aura", good luck.

Comment: Is this http://aura.codeplex.com/releases/view/63975 the Aura you talk about? Thanks!

Comment: I'll post a solution using the source code if my background allows me to do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question intrigued me, so I went into the deeps of Google Search and through several forums. What I found is this: it appears that there is no easy to edit the title bar in excel on Windows 7.

The only code I found that worked immediately when tested was to change the caption on the excel workbook:

```
Sub NameOfSub() 

Application.Caption = "MyApplication"

End Sub
```

Other than that, it is true that Aura (Aero?) has been used in the past to alter certain parts of office in the past, but I am uncertain as to its usefulness in Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks for the research. In my research I found the `.caption` member of the `application` object, so I thought that the `application.title.color` or something alike would be there as well. But it isn't. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: mechantid, no problem :) Hopefully the aura solution provided by @user1543250 is an effective one. Let us know how it goes  - ~JOL

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problems some days ago and found out that it can be possible if you will not use
`Application.DisplayStatusBar = True`
Only write where you need
`Application.StatusBar = "text here"`
And the colour of the bar will not change.